# Dual Wan & NAT with RV325

Tags: cisco, nat

I have a Cisco RV325 (Small Business Router), and two WAN ports with two different services.

WAN1: Comcast - Home Service (256Mbps Down, 30Mbps Up) - Single Dynamic IP
WAN2: Comcast - Business (100Mbps Down, 20Mbps Up) - 5 Block of Static IP's

I am using One to One NAT on several of the IP Addresses from WAN2

If I am not specifying NAT, I don't want to use WAN2, I want to stick with WAN1 for all other traffic.  Where WAN2 is for my PBX, Mail Server, and other servers.

Here is my WAN Setting Table:

[image]

Here is my One to One NAT:

[image]
Here is my Dual WAN configuration, this seems to be the only way the NATed addresses work:

[image]
And here is my Bandwith Managment screen:

[image]

What is happening now, is that sometimes while I am in load balancing mode, my non-natted traffic starts going over WAN2, and I don't want that.  While other times, it goes over WAN1.

How do I stop this from happening, forcing all non-natted traffic to go over WAN1?  I have tried turning Smart Link Backup on, but then it shuts down all of my NAT's from using WAN2 all together.

Comment: I think the closest you can come with that router is Protocol Bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my testing, I found out that it does work, however not 100% stable.  So what I did was got another router as a new gateway but same subnet.  I then added that to my network switch, and it worked perfectly, with that new switch, I am running the NAT, and for the NATed computers, I have set the new subnet.

Comment: I really think you could have done this with Protocol Binding. According to the manual, you could have selected all services for a particular source address and directed all that traffic through a particular WAN interface.

Comment: I could have done it with protocol bindings.  However I have multiple ips and I need the bindings from one up to go to one internal nat and so on.  So I don’t think that would work with this router based on my testing.

Comment: Several years later and I discovered SonicWall and PFSense, both support this very well!  I am now an avid PFSense user, and do everything with that!